# Javascript / Dreamweaver CS4 - How to control the .flv player?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, flv, dreamweaver

I need a solution to control the flv player of Dreamweaver CS4.. I think I have to use javascript for this. When you click on a div container it should start the video, another click on the same container will stop the video. - BTW I use the JQuery framework.. so may you can compress the code.. Thanks!!

Pseudo javascript:

```
If played == 0
On Click "#acooldiv"
PlayVideo "object flv"
played = 1


If played == 1
On Click "#acooldiv"
StopVideo "object flv"
played = 0
```

StopVideo should bring the video back to 0:00 (so its not a pause its a reset of the video playing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I'm not familliar with Dreamweaver, but why you want to control the flv player in that program? Don't you want to play a flv when it's in the (html)webpage and play it via javascript?
If you mean play FLV when its in the webpage:
You can communicate with the flv player [(see here)](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/156/tn_15683.html). But maybe better to embed these play/pause features in the flv player itself, because it really basic and probably most flv players already have it.